# How can I define my classes such that an XmlAttribute text (not its value) for a node can be specified at run-time, without custom serializers?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

How can I define my class structure such that I can assign the XmlAttribute text (not it's value) for a given element during run-time? For example, I have the following XML where I want to define a unique value for each instance of a specific XML note attribute text noted below as, "DEFINE_UNIQUE_FOR_EACH_INSTANCE":

```
<MyXml>
  <ZipCode DEFINE_UNIQUE_FOR_EACH_INSTANCE="Postal Code">90210</ZipCode>
  <State DEFINE_UNIQUE_FOR_EACH_INSTANCE="US State">CA</State>
</MyXml>
```

So I'd like to get something like:

```
<MyXml>
  <ZipCode labelText="Postal Code">90210</ZipCode>
  <State defaultValue="US State">CA</State>
</MyXml>
```

Here is my class definition for defining the first XML noted above:

```
[XmlRootAttribute]
public class MyXml
{
    public XmlValueAndAttribute ZipCode { get; set; }
    public XmlValueAndAttribute State { get; set; }

    public MyXml()
    { 
        ZipCode = new XmlValueAndAttribute(); State = new XmlValueAndAttribute();
    }
}
```

And

```
public class XmlValueAndAttribute
{
    [XmlAttribute("DEFINE_UNIQUE_FOR_EACH_INSTANCE")]
    public string AttributeValue { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public XmlValueAndAttribute() { }

    public XmlValueAndAttribute(string value, string attribute) 
    {
        Value = value;
        AttributeValue = attribute;
    }
}
```

And the usage of the class. Note the commented out code noting how I would like to make the attribute text assignment:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyXml xml = new MyXml();
    xml.ZipCode = new XmlValueAndAttribute("90210", "Postal Code" /*, "labelText"*/ )
    xml.State   = new XmlValueAndAttribute("CA", "US State" /*"defaultValue"*/);

    XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(xml.GetType());
    var xmlnsEmpty = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    xmlnsEmpty.Add("", "");
    x.Serialize(Console.Out, xml, xmlnsEmpty);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It will be difficult to do exactly what you are asking here.  What problem would the custom attribute name solve?  In other words, why do you even want/need the custom attribute name?

Comment: Hi Andrew. We spit out XML to our mobile apps and having dynamic attributes allow us to create a single C# XmlNode class that can be used for various purposes. Like, defining text for labels as well as the actual value for the label and defining default values within a list of items. Sort of like a general purpose C# class for one-way serialization.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by having your `XmlValueAndAttribute` class implement [`IXmlSerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public class XmlValueAndAttribute : IXmlSerializable
{
    public string AttributeName { get; set; }

    public string AttributeValue { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public XmlValueAndAttribute() { }

    public XmlValueAndAttribute(string value, string attribute, string attributeName)
    {
        Value = value;
        AttributeValue = attribute;
        AttributeName = attributeName;
    }

    #region IXmlSerializable Members

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    static XName nilName = XName.Get("nil", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        using (var subReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
        {
            var element = XElement.Load(subReader);
            reader.Read(); // Advance past the end of the element.
            if (element == null)
                return;
            Value = (bool?)element.Attribute(nilName) == true ? null : element.Value;
            var attr = element.Attributes().Where(a => a.Name != nilName && !a.IsNamespaceDeclaration).FirstOrDefault();
            if (attr != null)
            {
                AttributeName = XmlConvert.DecodeName(attr.Name.LocalName);
                AttributeValue = attr.Value;
            }
        }
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AttributeName))
            writer.WriteAttributeString(XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName(AttributeName), AttributeValue);
        if (Value == null)
            writer.WriteAttributeString("xsi", nilName.LocalName, nilName.Namespace.ToString(), XmlConvert.ToString(true));
        else
            writer.WriteString(Value);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Note that this implementation properly captures a null value for the `Value` property by writing `xsi:nil="true"`, but if `AttributeValue` is null while `AttributeName` is non-empty, the `AttributeValue` will get converted to an empty string when deserialized.

Comment: Boom! Home Run! Dropped your class in and got exactly what I was looking for. Initially I didn't want to go the IXmlSerializable route as I figured it would be too involved but looking at your code changes my mindset.  I understand that the class needs to implement the 'ReadXml', but for my usage, the XML will only be written out a client and never needs to be de-serialized, in this case, I can just have an empty ReadXml method, correct? Thanks a lot

Comment: @MoeHoward - `XAttribute` has an [explicit conversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342869%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `Nullable<bool>`, so what that line is doing is checking if the `"xsi:nil"` attribute is present and `true`, and if so, setting the `Value` to null, else to the element value.  (The cast operator has a [higher precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) than `?:` so it's just casting the `XAttribute`.)

Comment: @MoeHoward - if you don't want `ReadXml()` I'd suggest doing a `throw new NotImplementedException();` rather than leaving it empty.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to replace you `DEFINE_UNIQUE_FOR_EACH_INSTANCE` with something else, like a variable, you receive the following error:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

This indicates clearly, that the value of the parameter must exist at compile time. So in my opinion there seems to be no easy way except IL waeaving or some other hack.

Comment: Thanks Markus. Glad to read your comments confirming my initial and uncertain assumption. Guess I'll need to go with "DBC" suggestion using IXmlSerializable interface/implementation.